Can I Use Cookies with React Native Expo for Authentication?
When I am trying to get cookies from the server (backend), I am able to get cookies, but as far as I know, react native doesn't support cookies, and we have to save tokens in localStorage/AsyncStorege
const token = req.cookies?.AccessToken;
if (!token) throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized request");

const decoded = await jwt.decode(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
if (!decoded) throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized request");

const user = await UserModel.findById(decoded._id);
if (!user) {
    throw new ApiError(401, "Token Expired");
}

req.user = user;
next();

return res.status(202)
    .cookie("AccessToken", AccessToken, options)
    .cookie("RefreshToken", RefreshToken, options)
    .json(new ApiResponse(202, "Login Successful", { AccessToken, RefreshToken, user }));

Using this code, I can get and set cookies in React Native
I am using Expo Go and IOS Simulator for development.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
